# Confused about Backbone.js structure - trying to bootstrap a simple app

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

New to Backbone and I'm trying to get a simple application up and running. I'm running Grunt.js with Uglify to concat all of my files in the following order:

```
  'assets/js/main.min.js': [
    'collections/**/*.js',
    'models/**/*.js',
    'routers/**/*.js',
    'views/**/*.js',
    'app.js',],
```

I'm literally trying just to render a template into a `<div>` for starters. I've copied a lot from the Backbone.js todo applicaiton.

My very simple application files are as follows.

**views/offersList.js**

```
var PH = PH || {};

(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  PH.OffersList = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('.offers'),

    template: _.template($('#offers-list-template').html()),

    initialize: function () {
      this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
      this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    },

  });
})(jQuery);
```

**models/offer.js**

```
var PH = PH || {};

(function () {
  'use strict';

  PH.Offer = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
      name: "My Offer"
    }

  });
})();
```

**collections/offers.js**

```
var PH = PH || {};

(function () {
  'use strict';

  var Offers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PH.Offer
  });

  PH.OffersCollection = new Offers();

})();
```

and my **app.js**

```
var PH = PH || {};

$(function () {
  'use strict';

  // kick things off by creating the `PH`
  new PH.OffersList();

});
```

I've got a template in my `.html` file, inside my `.offers` div (I'm not even trying to render the data, just the template at this point:

```
<ul class="offers">
  <script id="offers-list-template" type="text/x-mustache-template">
    <h1>Offers List</h1>
    <p>Offers would go here</p>
  </script>
</ul>
```

It seems as if the model hasn't been bound, or isn't instantiated. I'm getting a

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined` on the line with `this.model.bind("change", this.render, this), this.render();`

I apologize for the wall of text, I'm just very new to this. Trying to wrap my head around this simple solution before I move on!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialize method has this in place

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
```

So it is expecting a **model to be passed in to the view** here

```
  // kick things off by creating the `PH`
  new PH.OffersList();
```

As you are **not passing the model to the view ..**

`model is set to undefined` and it is throwing an error

```
 new PH.OffersList({model: offersModel } );
```

But because this is the **OffersList** (Plural) you are talking about, I would expect to pass in a **collection here instead..**

***EDIT***

You need to pass in a new Instance of the model and not, model Directly.

```
PH.OffersList({ model: new PH.Offer() });
```

**OR**

```
var pHModel = new PH.Offer();

PH.OffersList({ model: pHModel  });
```

Comment: I see that now, thanks. So you can pass a **collection** to a view as well? I tried passing the model with `new PH.OffersList({ model: PH.Offer });` and I'm getting a new error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
            return r.apply(this, arguments);
        } has no method 'toJSON' `

Comment: Check edited code... Similarly you can pass in a collection too